# Problems altering current schema during oracle report execution

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I need to run a report with a user that uses objets from a diferent schema. I have used the before_parameter_form trigger to call a database procedure that executes an "alter session set current_schema = XXX" and with simple reports with only some querys in the data model the schema change works fine.

The problem comes when I try to run a report with some program units, for example a formula column that defines a cursor on a table from that schema. This kind of report fails during the first execution, throwing a "REP-1247: Report contains uncompiled PL/SQL" exception. After that first fail, the report works just fine while the database session that the reports server opens is alive.

My guess is that reports server first compiles the report, and if we make use of an object from another schema, it fails, but somehow also executes the before_parameter_form trigger so the default schema gets changed for that session, so afterwards the report keeps working just fine.

Is there any way of forcing the default_schema change before the report compilation?

Using synonyms is not an option, that's the main goal of all those changes.

Thanks!

Comment: Which report system are you using? And looks like you are talking about `current_schema` not `default_schema`.

Comment: Why are synonyms not an option?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov We use Oracle 11g but at least our Reports Builder is 11g version. And you're right, I meant current_schema, I made a mistake while writing my question, I've corrected it, thanks for the remark

Comment: @EdStevens It's a legacy aplication with an old db and the object names they used when developing it didn't follow any naming rules, so in order to avoid name duplicitys with objects in other schemas, dba decided to use private synonyms for old objects and public synonyms for new objects we create following naming rules. Nowadays we have about 1500 private synonyms for each user and that makes scalability an issue. New orders from the dba are to try to eliminate all synonyms, that's why they are not an option.